# What causes variables from one class to be affected by another?

Tags: java

I have a game I'm working on where a weapon, that belongs to a player, releases a projectile, in some cases, many projectiles.

However, when I pass an Image Class I created, called a Sprite, from the weapon to the projectile, any scaling I do to that individual projectile's sprite will affect the Weapon's Sprite as if the Sprite object for the weapon was static (it's not).

It starts from the weapon, in which I will post the relevant code for:

```
weaponProjectile[0] = new Pellet(releasedxCoor, releasedyCoor, mainChar.getDirection(), this, 0, projectileSprite);
    for(int i = 1; i < weaponProjectile.length; i++) {
        float accuracy = randomFloat((float)-2.5, (float)2.5);
        weaponProjectile[i] = new Pellet(releasedxCoor, releasedyCoor, mainChar.getDirection(), this, accuracy, projectileSprite);
    }
```

Here is the Pellet Constructor:

```
public Pellet(float xCoor, float yCoor, int direction, Blunderbuss fromWeapon, float accuracy, Sprite projectile) {
    super(xCoor, yCoor, direction, fromWeapon);
    this.xCoor = xCoor;
    this.yCoor = yCoor;

    this.projectileSpeed = fromWeapon.getProjectileSpeed() + randomFloat(-2, 2);
    this.pierceMax = fromWeapon.getPierce();
    this.pierce = pierceMax;
    this.damage = fromWeapon.getDamage();

    this.direction = direction;
    this.accuracy = accuracy;
    this.moving = projectile;
}
```

Here's where/how I scale images:

```
if(lifespan % 8 == 0) {
        this.projectileSpeed --;
        width--;
        height--;
        damage -= 2.5;
        this.moving.scaleWithRaster(0.9);
    }
```

The `scaleWithRaster` method:

```
public void scaleWithRaster(double scaleValue) {
    this.spriteSheet = imageScalar.getScaledImage(this.spriteSheet, scaleValue);
    this.xLength *= scaleValue;
    this.yLength *= scaleValue;
}
```

and the `ImageScalar` class:

```
public BufferedImage getScaledImage(BufferedImage image, double scaleFactor) {
    this.affine.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    this.op = new AffineTransformOp(affine, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    image = op.filter(image, null);

    return image;
}
```

The error I'm running into is the fact the raster for the image becomes too small nearly immediately, and the program crashes. Even if I shift the scale factor to 0.999999, it will still kill the program within a frame or so.

I am certain the issue revolves around the Sprite object being copied, as I tested with a non-static and static counter, that was incremented each time the method was called, on the Sprite object in question, and the values for both were identical.

I also know it is directly affecting the Weapon's sprite, as I had it draw the projectile from the weapon onto the screen, and it grew with the other projectiles. I have also tried setting it to final, which didn't prevent it form being scaled.

I've ensured that nothing regarding these images is static or public, so I'm extremely confused as to how this is happening. I had originally thought that I got passed by value and pass by references for java mixed up, but that is not the case, and such, each Sprite object should be a copy of the weapon's Sprite object, no?

**EDIT:** Solution has been found. I had to create a copy method within the sprite object, as I didn't fully understand the rules of Java's pass by value. Thanks to those who helped!

Comment: You are not copying the sprite object , it’s the same instance used in all your `Pellet` objects.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson So, how do I get it to copy? Isn't Java pass by values, so whatever I put into a method is simply a copy?

Comment: No it’s the opposite, either check if the sprite class has a copy method or a suitable constructor

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I created the Sprite class. How can I go about creating a copy method?

Comment: It's pass-by-value-except-the-value-you're-passing-is-a-reference-to-the-object-not-the-object-itself-so-objects-don't-get-copied. The problem with Java firmly declaring itself "pass by value" is that "pass by value" doesn't communicate the actual language semantics very well, and you end up always having to follow "pass by value" with an explanation anyway.

Comment: Don't edit your solution into your question.  Feel encouraged to post your own answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to remember. In Java all parameters are passed by value. But for non-primitives the **VALUE** is the **LINK** to the object. So if you pass an object - you pass the **LINK** to the object. As a result it stays mutable. The object passed to the method is the same object.

You can deep copy the object if needed. E.g. using any kind of serialization. E.g. - [using Jason](https://github.com/azee/java-utils#beans).

Also you can create a copy constructor or implement Cloneable interface and pass a copy (looks like your objects are not complicated).

AFAIK, apache commons also contains deep object copy functions.